# How do you read a file and display in listbox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I was trying to display data from file in a list saved on the hard drive by clicking on a button, however I'm not sure on haw to do it properly:

```
Private Sub btnListRecipes_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnListRecipes.Click
    Dim TextLine As String
    If System.IO.File.Exists(Filename) = True Then
        Dim RecipeReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Filename)
        Do While RecipeReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = TextLine & RecipeReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
        Loop
        lstRecipes.Text = TextLine.Text
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If
End Sub
```

I would be really grateful for assistance :D

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub btnListRecipes_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnListRecipes.Click
    Try
        lstRecipes.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(FileName))
    Catch
        MsgBox("Unable to read file")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
lstRecipes.Items.Add(TextLine.Text)
```

More specifically before it jumps to the next item in the list, so this would go right after your assignment of `TextLine`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Public Shared listTXT, listOfTxt, listOfTxtFile As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path As String = "C:\myDirectory\"

    Dim parentinfo As New DirectoryInfo(path)

    ' Store Text file name in a list
    For Each txtFile As FileSystemInfo In parentinfo.GetFileSystemInfos()
        listTXT.Add(txtFile.Name)
    Next

    ' Store Path of Text file in a list
    For noOfTxtFile = 0 To listTXT.Count - 1

        Dim pathOfFile As String = path & listTXT(noOfTxtFile)
        listOfTxtFile.Add(pathOfFile)

        Dim obj As System.IO.StreamReader
        obj = System.IO.File.OpenText(pathOfFile)

        While Not obj.EndOfStream
            listOfTxt.Add(obj.ReadLine)
        End While

    Next

    Dim lineOfTxt As Integer
    Dim txt As String

    For lineOfTxt = 0 To listOfTxt.Count - 1
        txt = listOfTxt(lineOfTxt)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(txt)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```